# ORA-8103: Object no longer exist(On standby db)

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, high-availability, standby

I'm using oracle 12C and one of my partitioned table exist on primary database. 
However, on my standby db ,when I'm selecting data from the same table, then it's throwing below error:

```
    ORA-08103 'object no longer exist'
```

It's very strange my standby is behaving like this which is in sync with primary.
 All other objects as well as tables ,I'm able to access and there data from other tables as well.
 What could possibly causing this error and how to troubleshoot this? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have much experience with standby, but I've seen this error happen frequently when users are mixing reads and truncates.  Was the table truncated, or dropped and recreated?  Or was there some partition maintenance that happened in the middle of your query?  Maybe check `DBA_OBJECTS.LAST_DDL_TIMESTAMP` and find out what changed the table at that time.

Comment: Thank you @JonHeller for coming up and taking look into my problem. I found the last ddl execution details. However, auditing isn't enabled into our database. Could you please let us know how to find the specific event details(on a particular time),if any.  -Thanks

Comment: Auditing in Oracle is a horrible mess, there's no simple way to 100% audit everything.  It would probably be easier to try to look through your code and look for keywords like TRUNCATE and DROP.